# Where does Crystal install shards?

Tags: crystal-lang

When I run `shards install`, where does Crystal install shard dependencies from `shard.yml` on my system? RubyGems installs gems in a hidden folder `~/. gem/ruby/`, however, I cannot find a similar location like `~/.crystal` or `~/.shard` in my home directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crystal resolves and installs dependencies into the `lib` folder of your project.

https://crystal-lang.org/reference/the_shards_command/index.html#shards-install